# Margin style has no effect in qt rich text label

Tags: python, fonts, pyqt, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

I am using [icomoon app](https://icomoon.io/app) to use svgs as glyph in a custom font.

Since the image

[image]

has multiple colors, icomoon generates multiple glyph for the same character. Proper styling are then supposed to set the appropriate colors and layer them.

When i attempt to display the glyph in a QLabel, the margin-left style seems to ignored however. I have tried layering different glyph, margin-right, and different units, but the margin is never applied:

[image]

I use pyqt

```
import typing as t

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class CardViewWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent: t.Optional[QtWidgets.QWidget] = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        font = QtGui.QFont('icomoon', 40)

        self._info_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)

        self._info_label.setFont(font)
        self._info_label.setText(
            '<span style="color: #aae0fa">&#xe900;</span><span style="margin-left:-1em; color: #061922;">&#xe901;</span>'
        )
        self._info_label.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.RichText)


        self._layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        self._layout.addWidget(self._info_label)

        self.setLayout(self._layout)
```

Is it just not possible to use margin for text like this in qt? It displays correctly in a browser, and margin is on the qts supported css list.

Thanks.

Comment: Try: `margin-left:-10px;`. Probably `em` and such like aren't supported.

Comment: I have tried, it has no effect.