# How to use padding, margin, etc. in Qt rich text at the span level?

Tags: python, html, css, pyside, pyside6

For my QTextEdit I wanted to bring across something extremely basic, nested highlights, that I made whilst messing around on a [W3Schools "Try It!"](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_inline-block_span1) which looks like this.

[image: "W3Schools" result]

As far as I can tell I have only used things in the [Supported HTML Subset](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html) of Qt (see the HTML in the code below, only padding, margin, and background-color are used).

I could not get a similar render, only background-color seemed to work.

I made a fresh project to make a simple test using hard coded HTML/styling rather than my procedural generation, and still it does not render as it should.

Here is the code.

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTextEdit, QMainWindow

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

test_window = QMainWindow()
test_text_edit = QTextEdit()

html = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
span.a {
  padding: 2px;
  margin: -2px;
  background-color: orange;
}
span.b {
  background-color: powderblue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>volutpat. <span class="a">Aliquam <span class="b">venenatis</span> gravida</span> nisl</div>
</body>
</html>
"""
test_text_edit.setHtml(html)
test_window.setCentralWidget(test_text_edit)

test_window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is the result, lacking a stark amount of the styling, am I crazy or should this not look basically identical according to the documentation? Not lacking the padding that makes the "nesting" clearer?

[image: My QTextEdit result]

It seems the margin issue is not unknown [Margin style has no effect in qt rich text label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51163854/margin-style-has-no-effect-in-qt-rich-text-label) but no one answered this question either.

Anyone know any fixes/workarounds? Or where this is documented as a known limitation of Qt?

[how I use the QTextEdit in pyqt5 to show all style of the html (including the style of css)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55545738/how-i-use-the-qtextedit-in-pyqt5-to-show-all-style-of-the-html-including-the-st) is also related but is not a duplicate, it merely points to the document of what CSS it follows, it does not cover why it doesn't follow, or how to follow the standard it says it follows.

Comment: span is by default an inline element and does not respond on vertical padding and height. To solve this, use `span { display: inline-block; }`. Another thing is that you have to add margin, padding and border to calculatie the total size/length of an element. Using `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` will keep the border and padding inside an element. The margin is always outside an element.

Comment: I doubt it's actually doable with Qt: if you read the `margin-*` property definitions, it always refers to the *paragraph* margins. The only possibility would be to subclass QTextDocument and/or QTextEdit and manually paint a background using a custom user format to identify the "special" highlighting. If you want full HTML/CSS support, use a [QWebEngineView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html)

Comment: @bron Unfortunately we're talking about a custom (and partial) implementation of stylesheets that only supports a subset of HTML and CSS 2.1, so none of your suggestions will work.

Comment: Note: remember that what is shown on any Qt rich-text based control uses a QTextDocument (even QLabel, even if it's not publicly accessible), which provides limited capabilities for text laying out and rendering, as it's not intended for advanced features as a standard Html renderer would. And that's understandable: standard UI controls should only provide basic features in order to keep good performance; `setHtml()` does **not** put *that* HTML on the text control, but parses the given contents using the Qt html parser and generates/changes the underlying QTextDocument.